Erela.js WebSocket Endpoint Update for Lavalink
I'm facing an issue with updating the WebSocket endpoint configuration in Erela.js to connect to my Lavalink server. I've recently upgraded my Lavalink server to a newer version, which requires using a different WebSocket endpoint (/v4/websocket). Despite trying to update the Erela.js library and all its plugins using npm update erela.js, I haven't been successful in resolving the issue.
How to properly update the WebSocket endpoint in Erela.js to connect to the new Lavalink version? I've attempted modifying the configuration, but I keep encountering errors.
Detailed error:
2024-04-21T00:47:28.172Z  INFO 29 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /, client=IP LOL
2024-04-21T00:47:28.358Z  WARN 29 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] lavalink.server.config.WebsocketConfig   : This is the old Lavalink websocket endpoint. Please use /v4/websocket instead. If you are using a client library, please update it to a Lavalink v4 compatible version or use Lavalink v3 instead

